# Spring 4.1 @JmsListener configuration

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-jms

I would like to use the new annotations and features provided in Spring 4.1 for an application that needs a JMS listener.

I've carefully read the notes in the [Spring 4.1 JMS improvements post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/30/spring-4-1-s-upcoming-jms-improvements) but I continue to miss the relationship between `@JmsListener` and maybe the `DestinationResolver` and how I would setup the application to indicate the proper `Destination` or `Endpoint`.

Here is the suggested use of @JmsListener

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    @JmsListener(containerFactory = "myContainerFactory", destination = "myQueue")
    public void processOrder(String data) { ... }
}
```

Now, I can't use this in my actual code because the "myQueue" needs to be read from a configuration file using `Environment.getProperty()`.

I can setup an appropriate myContainerFactory with a `DestinationResolver` but mostly, it seems you would just use `DynamicDestinationResolver` if you don't need JNDI to lookup a queue in an app server and didn't need to do some custom reply logic.  I'm simply trying to understand how Spring wants me to indicate the name of the queue in a parameterized fashion using the `@JmsListener` annotation.

Further down the blog post, I find a reference to this Configurer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    registrar.setDefaultContainerFactory(defaultContainerFactory());

    SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
    endpoint.setDestination("anotherQueue");
    endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> {
        // processing
    });
    registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
}
```

Now, this makes some amount of sense and I could see where this would allow me to set a Destination at runtime from some external string, but this seems to be in conflict with using `@JmsListener` as it appears to be overriding the annotation in favor of `endpoint.setMessageListener` in the code above.

Any tips on how to specify the appropriate queue name using `@JmsListener`?

Comment: By using a placeholder. `destination="${name.of.your.property}"`.

Comment: I would prefer not to use `PropertyPlaceHolderConfiguration` in favor of `Environment.getProperty` but clearly I can't take that route as a parameter to an annotation.

Comment: Actually you will use a `PropertySourcePlaceHolderConfigurer` which basically does the same as `Environment.getProperty` does (it consults all `PropertySource`s. Could you elaborate why you would prefer the `Environment.getProperty` over the placeholder in this case?

Comment: It just seemed like using `@PropertySource` in `@Configuration` beans was the latest recommended way to read from configuration.  I was trying for a "no XML" approach.

Comment: And why would a `@PropertySource` wouldn't work with a placeholder? It works the same. The only difference is that you need to use a `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer`. So that fact of using a placeholder doesn't mean you cannot use `@PropertySource` anymore.

Comment: I wanted to only use @PropertySource and didn't want to have the redundancy of multiple methods for properties.  It's not a big deal, just didn't want the additional overhead. I'll just setup the placeholder and use SpEL to parameterize the destination.

Comment: It isn't SpEL it is just a placeholder. I don't really see the redundancy in this case but that is probably my lack of vision then.

Comment: I am +1 with @M.Deinum here and would be interested to understand what the issue is using Placeholder.

Comment: I'm not against using a placeholder, but my configuration is already being set using `@Configuration` beans with `@PropertySource`.  It's trivial to setup the Placeholder and I don't have a problem doing so, but not only is it redundant it seems like I should be able to set the destination in a way that does not require the destination to be passed in via annotation.  What if I wanted to determine the destination dynamically at runtime? Thanks, @Stéphane Nicoll.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, would you mind repeating your comment in an answer. I think it deserves to be there. It's not immediately obvious from the documentation that you can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could eventually do that right now but it's a bit convoluted. You can set a custom `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` using `JmsListenerConfigurer`

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setEndpointRegistry(customRegistry());
    }

}
```

and then override the registerListenerContainer method, something like

```
public void registerListenerContainer(JmsListenerEndpoint endpoint, JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
    // resolve destination according to whatever -> resolvedDestination
    ((AbstractJmsListenerEndpoint)endpoint).setDestination(resolvedDestination);
    super.registerListenerContainer(endpoint, factory);
}
```

But we could do better. Please watch/vote for [SPR-12280](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12289)

Comment: Has there been any update with this? The ticket appears to have been declined but this is 5 years old now

Answer (score 17):

Also note that depending on use case you can already parameterize using properties file per environment and PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

```
@JmsListener(destinations = "${some.key}")
```

As per https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12289

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Templating is demonstrated for @Value annotations but it wasn't made clear in the docs that it was available more generally. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In case people are using `@JmsListener` with spring boot, you do not have to configure `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. It work's out the box

Sample:

**class**

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${spring.activemq.queue.name}")
    public void receiveEntityMessage(final TextMessage message) {
    // process stuff 
}
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.activemq.queue.name=some.weird.queue.name.that.does.not.exist
```

**Spring boot output**

```
[26-Aug;15:07:53.475]-[INFO ]-[,]-[DefaultMes]-[o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer ]-[931 ]-Successfully refreshed JMS Connection 
[26-Aug;15:07:58.589]-[WARN ]-[,]-[DefaultMes]-[o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer ]-[880 ]-Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'some.weird.queue.name.that.does.not.exist' - trying to recover. Cause: User user is not authorized to read from some.weird.queue.name.that.does.not.exist 
[26-Aug;15:07:59.787]-[INFO ]-[,]-[DefaultMes]-[o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer ]-[931 ]-Successfully refreshed JMS Connection 
[26-Aug;15:08:04.881]-[WARN ]-[,]-[DefaultMes]-[o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer ]-[880 ]-Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'some.weird.queue.name.that.does.not.exist' - trying to recover. Cause: User user is not authorized to read from some.weird.queue.name.that.does.not.exist
```

This proves that @JmsListener is able to pickup property values from application.properties without actually setting up any explicit `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

I hope this helps!